# How to best merge four large tables

Tags: mysql, merge

I have 4 largish MYSQL tables.
Each with about 10Million rows.
The tables only contain an ID, which is unique.

Some of the tables might contain duplicates of ID's in other tables.  I want to just keep one of them in the final merged table.

So basically I need to export all 4 tables and combine them into one large table of over 40Million rows with no duplicates.

What is the best way to achieve all this, with relatively larger files??
I'm running into limits with exporting/importing in phpmyadmin, so will likely have to do this from the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned, MySQL supports an option for `INSERT IGNORE...` which means *try* the insert, but for each row, if it conflicts with a unique key (or results in another error like failing a NOT NULL or a FOREIGN KEY check), it simply skips the row and goes on to insert the next row.

You probably know the `mysqldump` tool that comes with MySQL. It has an option to export data with the `INSERT IGNORE` syntax.

You'll also want to omit the CREATE TABLE because if you're going to import four datasets to the same destination table, you don't need to create the table four times.

So here's what I recommend:

On one of your servers, get the table definition only. If they're all identical, it doesn't matter which server you get this from:

```
mysqldump --no-data mydatabase mytable > create.sql
```

Then get data only from each of your four servers:

```
mysqldump --no-create-info --insert-ignore mydatabase mytable > data1.sql
```

(likewise for data2.sql, data3.sql, data4.sql, one for each server)

Copy the dump files to the server where you want to merge the data.

Create the table:

```
mysql mydestdatabase < create.sql
```

Load all the data:

```
pv -pert data*.sql | mysql mydestdatabase
```

I like to use `pv -pert` for this because it shows a progress bar. You might have to install `pv` because it's not present by default on most systems. If you don't want to do this, just use `cat`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do four "insert into" commands, or the UNION operator might work, too.

Comment: The 4 tables are all on seperate servers.  I need to dump/export them.  Then how to I import them but merge at the same time?  Or do I just do four seperate inserts, and the duplicate ID's will get ignored?? Since theyre uniques?

Comment: You're already doing a dump/export ... could you do something to remove the duplicates before you do the import?

Answer (score 0):

MySql does have [INSERT IGNORE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) which allows you to happily insert from all of the tables one after another. The DBMS will take care (in the sense of discard) the duplicates.

This might not be the most efficient option but I assumed that it would be a one time operation.

Answer (score 0):

Define the 4 tables as each having the ID being a Unique, Primary Key.
Then simply do an Outer Join of all 4 tables.

Comment: Theyre all on different servers.  I dont want to import them into the same DB as seperate tables and then Join.    Preferably Id want to do it in one operation.  join them/insert them together all at once, into the final table.   How would I go about doing this??  Like after I've mysqldumped all into SQL files, is there a command to merge/join them before inserting?  Or is the only way to insert all seperately and then join?